# Image not uploading to the required Path (Laravel Framework)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have been trying to make the image submitted through the image form submit to a directory. the directory  "mywebsite.com/asset/profile", Please how do I do it. below is the Html code and the Controller code. It's a laravel Framework.
HTML CODE//

```
<div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="image" required>Select photo</label>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" required> 
            <span class="form-text text-muted">Accepted formats:png, jpg.</span>
          </div>
```

Controller Code//

```
     {
         if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $location = '/asset/profile';
        $filename = time() . '_' . $user->username . '.jpg';
        $request->image->move($location, $filename);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix could be this -

```
$request->image->move(public_path('asset/profile'), $filename );
```

This will store image to `public/asset/profile` folder.

Comment: It's still not stored in the path, Any other method of Posting??

Comment: Check if you may have forgotten to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form? 

Just to know, Have you tried Intervention Image  [http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation] yet? It's a cool library for image manipulations.

Comment: No, I haven't. I don't know how to use it

Comment: should I send the whole code, the question I posted is just a snippet. Maybe the problem is from another line of Code

Comment: Please share on pastebin and share the link here.

Comment: Thanks for your Time Raju Rayhan, I have been able to fix it. I really appreciate it. I will love to keep being your friend. Can we chat on WhatsApp?